# Drupal analyze site structure / reverse engineer site structure

Tags: drupal

I have been assigned to support a Drupal site which is practically a mess. I cannot understand the structure of nodes and the types of content and how it finally appears. I wonder if you know any tool to analyse - reverse engineer the site structure and the way the content is categorized and displayed. Thanks in advance. 
PS:There are certain nodes / pages (ex:/user) that I can find nowhere to edit.

Comment: I'm not sure of any site structure analyzing tools, but /user is a page generated by Drupal core to allow users to login. It is not an editable page (at least not directly). It sounds like you haven't worked with Drupal before, either. I would recommend setting up a playground Drupal site so you can familiarize yourself with Drupal before trying to make any changes.

Comment: Do you know how I can edit-customize the /user page? Thnx for answering.

Comment: See my answer below. It really depends on what you are trying to change at /user, and whether you are referring to the login page or the user profile page, both of which reside at /user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of any site structure analyzing tools, but /user is a page generated by Drupal core to allow users to login. It is not an editable page (at least not directly). It sounds like you haven't worked with Drupal before, either. I would recommend setting up a playground Drupal site so you can familiarize yourself with Drupal before trying to make any changes.

**Customizing /user:**

If you just want to change some of the HTML on the user profile page (not the login page), you can use the [user-profile.tpl.php template](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user-profile.tpl.php/6).

You can also set up a [theme template for the login page](http://drupal.org/node/19855).

If you want to add more fields (such as a phone number or location field) to users' profiles, you can do so using the core Profile module.

If you want to do more advanced customization of the login form, you will have to look into creating your own module and using [hook_form_alter()](http://drupal.org/node/651106).